# Does a passing of an object to a block guarantee that its lifecycle will be retained?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, retain

Let's assume I have the following typedef:

```
typedef void (^myBlock)(id);
```

And I have some method *myMethod* accepting *myBlock* as an argument and yielding some *id* variable to it:

```
void myMethod(id myObj, myBlock block) {
    // ...
    block(myObj);
    // ...
}
```

So if I have the following:

```
- (void) someMethod {
    __block id myObj; // Some initialization local to the scope of someMethod;
    // myObj = ... some assignment to myObj so it is not nil...

    dispatch_async(someQueue(), ^{
        // (*) Some long, possibly multi-queued and multi-blocked, processing, 
        // so we are sure that someMethod will run out:
        // ...

        // 1. Can I be sure that myObj is still alive and actual here 
        // after the long processing (*)?

        myMethod(myObj, ^(id myObj) {
            // (**) Some long, possibly multi-queued, processing here too...

            // 2. Can I be sure that myObj is still alive and actual here 
            // after the long processing (**) finishes?
        })
    })
}
```

do I have to **specially retain myObj** so it would live across different queues/blocks?

Sorry if I'm asking something obvious and enough documented - I've just started learning Objective-C in the time, when ARC is likely a default so it does not require me to care much about these retain counts, autoreleases and other stuff, and think about them only in the situations like I described here.

Comment: why are you using `__block`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Can I be sure that myObj is still alive and actual here after the long processing (*)?

Yes, and even if you weren't using the block specifier because the block inside the block retains it.

> 1. Can I be sure that myObj is still alive and actual here after the long processing (**) finishes?

Yes.Every variable used inside a block is retained by ARC.

**PS:** All this with ARC.

Comment: "even if you weren't using the block specifier" in fact, if they were not using ARC, using `__block` would specifically make it *not* retained

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Can I be sure that myObj is still alive and actual here after the long processing (*)?

Yes. Normally, free variables in a block are retained by the block when it is copied. However, this is a `__block` variable. In ARC, `__block` variables are also retained by the block (however, that is not the case in MRC).

> 1. Can I be sure that myObj is still alive and actual here after the long processing (**) finishes?

This question isn't related to blocks capturing variables at all. Here, `myObj` is a parameter, i.e. a local variable, not captured from the surrounding scope. So the question really is, does the argument point to a valid object when the block is called? Since `myMethod()` simply synchronously calls its `block` argument with the `myObj` argument that it gets, under ARC, nothing should go wrong assuming that the arguments were valid when `myMethod` was called (i.e. in the outer block). This is true since we agreed that `myObj` was valid there from (1) above.