# Does calling of a block with a variable guarantee that its lifecycle will be retained?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

I have some typedef:

```
typedef void (^myBlock)(SomeObject);
```

And I have some object

```
@interface SomeObject : NSObject
@end

// Method of some arbitrary class
- (void) someMethod1 {
    SomeObject *someObject = [[SomeObject alloc] init];

    myBlock block = ^(SomeObject obj){
        // When _block(someObject)_ will be called inside someQueue - 
        // Is it guaranteed that someObject will be alive, retained inside me?       

        // Do something complex and involving (or not) obj ...    
    }

    dispatch_async(someQueue, ^{
        // Some bunch of code - after which we are sure that 
        // by the next line someMethod1 will run out, so its scope is lost

        block(someObject);
    });
}
```

The question is put inside the *block* variable's block: is it guaranteed that someObject object we pass to the block *block* inside *someQueue* queue will be **alive and retained** inside the *block* block?

This question is a bit more complex variation of the question I've just asked: [Does a passing of an object to a block guarantee that its lifecycle will be retained?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901447/does-a-passing-of-an-object-to-a-block-guarantees-that-its-lifecycle-will-be-ret).

Comment: I think that you could ask it in the comments of my answer.

Comment: Thanks, @RamyAlZuhouri! No more similar questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that what you're asking is the same of the previous question.The only difference here is that you aren't calling a method inside the block, but you are calling a block.
Maybe my answer wasn't enough clear: everything is retained inside a block, even a block is retained.

```
dispatch_async(someQueue, ^{
    // Some bunch of code - after which we are sure that 
    // by the next line someMethod1 will run out, so its scope is lost

    block(someObject);
});
```

Inside the block you call someObject, so someObject is captured.Also the block is captured.

Comment: "If you don't use ARC you could call [myBlock retain] and this retains the block." What? No. "Without ARC the way of doing this was to use a __block variable." What's "this"? I think you got it backwards.

Comment: Do you talk about "block"?

Comment: No, I am saying that "If you don't use ARC you could call [myBlock retain]" is wrong. If you are not using ARC, you would not call `[myBlock retain]`

Comment: So I removed all the things about non-ARC.

Answer (score 1):

the block and all it will use is retained until after the block is executed.. it is **captured**